# How to call a method in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am new with web service and .net.
I would like to call a method from aspx.cs file, in my web service.
How do i do that?

```
protected void SearchRec(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ....
    }

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void example(string text_to_search)
    {
      .....//call SearchRec here
    }
```

Comment: Are they in the same class?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want your code behind to call a web service? Why don't you just directly call the function instead?

Comment: What does the method do?

Comment: I want the web service to call the method in the code behind

Comment: search specific data in the database

Comment: Why are you using a `WebMethod`? ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, just write :

```
public void example(string text_to_search)
{
    this.SearchRec(text_to_search, null);
}
```

If they are both declared in the same class.

**UPDATE:**
You have to transfer SearchRec logic and other similar methods to separate class. In your aspx.cs you can use it creating an instance of that class. And the same in webservice method. You can create an instance of that class and call it's methods.

Also, these topics can be usefull [Difference between webservice, web methods & server side code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952400/difference-between-webservice-web-methods-server-side-code) , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: they don't declared in the same class

Comment: @user3025441 can you create an instance of that class and call its method (you will need to change protected to public to call it straight)?