# In Which scenario I should use Web Method and Server side code for Ajax using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, webmethod

I am trying learn about **Ajax using ASP.Net**

When I google it to do ajax, there are **so many ways they are sending data and retrieving data like (thorough: webservice /  webmethod / server side code)**.

I know what is the use of **WebService**.

But I didn't get the clear information **about webmethod**. And what will be the **difference between webmethod and server side code**

I saw this [Difference between webservice, web methods & server side code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952400/difference-between-webservice-web-methods-server-side-code) as well. But they didn't give more information about webmethod.

> I want to know in which scenario basis that I should go with webMethod and Server side code.

Please give me a real time example

Comment: @baao closing this question was a bad move, the question and answer you provided was obviously too techy for this person to understand. I could have given a more basic answer to this question.

Comment: @baao Hello, that suggested link is entirely wrong to my topic.

Comment: @Chris Why are they doing like this?. This is so embarrassing me.

Comment: @mohamed_hafil Because they just want rep for doing things and is probably on a powertrip

Comment: You don't get rep for closing questions @Chris. This particular question qualifies to be voted to close as too-broad and a duplicate of given answers. Basically the question boils down to what is the difference between a backend and a frontend - once OP has learned about that, he will understand the rest too

Comment: @baao Do you have brain?. I didn't ask the question about front end and back end code. That's totally unrelated to my question.